# c# parse google trends csv no apparent delimiter

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, delimiter

I'm trying to parse csv files from google trends, but there doesn't appear to be any delimiter between columns? Is there any way to go about getting this working so I can get data separated into columns after parsing, or is the best that I can do to just have each row in one column.

I've tried numerous csv readers:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx
http://www.stellman-greene.com/CSVReader/

I could try to substring out the data in each row, but that seems like a very poor solution.

Example csv file from google trends:
http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=stackoverflow&date=all&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me the columns are delimited with tabs (U+0009), aren’t they? Just do

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"trends.csv", true))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var items = line.Split('\t');
        if (items.Length == 3) // recognizing the header etc. left as an exercise for the reader
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}, value = {1}, error = {2}", items[0], items[1], items[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you've saved me a ton of time. I somehow blindly missed that the delimiters were tabs. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's encoded in UTF-16 with a delimiter of tab (U+0009).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible issues why it does not get parsed well by those libraries:

1. The first 4 lines could possibly
   "trick" those parsers into believing
   there are only 2 columns
2. This is not really a [**CSV (Comma-Separated Values)**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) file, tabs are used instead of commas

---

[image]

---

It's easy and straightforward to write your own parser for this particular case (there are no escaped tabs in values):

1. Open the file
2. Skip the first 5 lines
3. For each line you read, split it by `\t` and get column values